# Robot leg PrivateModule and binding overriding

Tags: java, guice

I'm having problems with overriding bindings of PrivateModule.
Here is my example project:

http://pastebin.com/3BxUT90H

So i have 3 cars, each gets Transmission and Engine from CommonModule.

And i bind Driveline to each car separately with annotations, so each gets different class.
So standard robot leg problem/solution.

But now lets presume i have 10 different cars and i would like to change the Engine in just one module.
I could throw out Engine from `CommonModule` and define Engine in all 10 modules.
But better solution would be to override Engine binding in just that one class.

How can i achieve this?

If i `bind(Engine.class).to(PetrolEngine.class);` in Module3 i naturally get A binding to Engine was already configured at.

Thats why we have Modules.override.

But

```
 Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(
                commonModule,
                module1,
                module2,
                Modules.override(commonModule).with(module3)
        );
```

gives me the same error.

So is there a way to define `PrivateModule` and override binding that is defined in `AbstractModule`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead passing CommonModule as parameter to `Guice.createInjector()` method you can explicitly install it in each of ModuleN modules.

So Module3 definition would look like

```
class Module3 extends PrivateModule {
   @Override
   protected void configure() {
      install(new CommonModule());
      bind(Car.class).annotatedWith(Green.class).to(Car.class);
      expose(Car.class).annotatedWith(Green.class);
      bind(Driveline.class).to(FourWheelDrive.class);
   }
}
```

Then you may specify a module which just adds binding for the engine

```
class PetrolEngineModule extends AbstractModule {
   @Override
   protected void configure() {
      bind(Engine.class).to(PetrolEngine.class);
   }
}
```

and `Modules.override()` should work:

```
Modules.override(module3).with(new PetrolEngineModule())
```

To avoid putting call to install in each of defined modules you can create abstract superclass `AbstractCarModule`. Put `install()` in that module and use it as super class for each of `ModuleN` modules.

Comment: I don't understand what do i override with Module3.
If i put install() in Module3 where i have bind(Engine.class).to(PetrolEngine.class) i get A binding to Engine was already configured at CommonModule.
http://pastebin.com/LpZ2pWMP
Where can i put override then?

Comment: I edited the answer to look like what I really had in mind ... But honestly IMO the solution is not much better than just putting specific engine binding in each of the modules (like you originally wrote in the query)